# Adding Strings to NsMutableSets

Tags: objective-c, nsmutableset

If I have two string objects that both have value "hi", and I add them to an NSMutableSet, are they treated as different objects or not? Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Did you try it first? What were the results?

Comment: Well, it doesn't duplicate them. But they are different objects, right...?

Comment: But they are both equal. `NSSet` only keeps objects with different values based in the `isEqual:` method of the object.

Answer (score 2):

Beside the correct comment of @rmaddy, there is a fundamental problem with it: It is simply mostly impossible to guarantee that no objects are *equal* in a set. (It is easy to guarantee that the are not identical.) This would imply to recheck the equaty of all objects (expensive), when one changes (mostly impossible to detect). This is, because `NSSet` does not copy its content objects.

Let's have an example:

```
NSMutableString *first = [@"Amin" mutableCopy];
NSMutableString *second = [@"Amin Negm" mutableCopy];
NSSet *set = [NSSet setWithObjects:first, second];

[first appendString:@" Negm"];
```

Both objects are equal than, but none is removed. (Which one?)